# Send an open sound control style message on a Raspberrypi Pico W

Tags: sockets, micropython

Trying to figure this one out. I'm trying to send an OSC style message to a lighting console to trigger an event. I'm using a Raspberry Pi Pico W and coding in Micropython. The Wi-Fi connects and gives positive feedback. Should be fairly simple but no data seems to be getting through.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import network
import machine
import usocket as socket
from time import sleep
import config

#set up onboard led to turn on when connected
led = machine.Pin('LED', machine.Pin.OUT)
led.on()
sleep(.1)
led.off()
sleep(.1)

# Wi-Fi configuration
SSID = config.wifi
PASSWORD = config.password

# Static IP address configuration
ip_address = config.picoIP
subnet_mask = "255.0.0.0"
gateway = "192.168.1.1"  # Replace with your gateway IP

# HOG4 OSC settings
hog4_ip = config.hogIP  # Replace with your HOG4's IP address
hog4_port = config.hogport  # Replace with the HOG4's OSC port

# GPIO pin configuration
gpio_pin = machine.Pin(7, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)

# Connect to Wi-Fi
def connect_to_wifi(SSID, PASSWORD):
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    if not wlan.isconnected():
        print("Connecting to WiFi...")
        wlan.active(True)
        led.off()
        wlan.ifconfig((ip_address, subnet_mask, gateway, "8.8.8.8"))  # Set static IP
        wlan.connect(SSID, PASSWORD)
        while not wlan.isconnected():
            sleep(5)  # Add a delay of 5 seconds
    print("Connected to WiFi")
    print("IP Address:", wlan.ifconfig()[0])
    # LED on for wifi connected
    led.on()

def send_osc_message():
        # create UDP socket
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
                  
        # Construct the OSC message             
        address = "/hog/hardware/go/1"
        data = b",i" + bytearray([1])  # OSC argument for integer (1)
        message = address.encode() + data
    
        # send message
        s.sendto(message, (hog4_ip, 7001))
        print("Sent OSC message to HOG4")
        print(message)         
        s.close()
    
# Main program loop
def main():
    connect_to_wifi(SSID, PASSWORD)
    while True:
        if gpio_pin.value() == 0:  # GPIO 7 is LOW
            send_osc_message()
            sleep(0.5)  # debounce the button
        sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```